# Dell PS6510 96tb raw turns into raid 6 with 26tb useable?

Tags: raid, storage-area-network, dell

I am confused by the usable capacity i am getting from a PS6510 with 48 x 2TB Disks. So total this Array has 96TB RAW but after the initial configuration I manage to connect to the array and apply a RAID 6 configuration. The GUI notes that the usable capacity should be 69.08TB with 47 disk in use and one spare. After applying the config the arrays usable capacity immediately jumps up to 26.64TB and has stayed there for the past 5 hours. There are no errors on the array but the RAID Status is "verifying" and progress is at 6%.

I have looked all over and cannot find any documentation on this behavior, and it is pretty concerning for a storage device to give you only 28% usable capacity even with any RAID configuration.

Is this normal? Does it just need to complete verification of the RAID before it will give access to the whole 69.08TB capacity? And if so why would it give access to 26.64TB before verification has completed?

UPDATE: after completing the verification the PS6510 remained at 26TB of usable storage. I then safely rebooted the device and it defaulted the other Type 10 controller. When viewing the disks on this controller it had more then half marked as foreign disks instead of online. From there i managed to readd those disks and the available space jumped from 26 to about 53TB still 16TB shy of the orginal configuration estimate of 69TB. at this point I have absolutely no idea why it is creating a 53TB storage pool instead of a 69TB storage pool.....

Comment: I want to make sure I'm understanding this correctly. You're creating a single RAID-6 across 48 members? If so, that is not going to work well at all.

Comment: wow i wish i had 48 PS6510 a couple PB of storage would be super cool. But no it is a single PS6510 which has 47 disk in a RAID6 and one spare drive.

Comment: also you are correct about creating a RAID across mutiple members. As far as I know for the PS series only one RAID can be configured per member.

Comment: No, a single PS6510 with 48 disks and a single RAID-6 abstraction with all those disks joined. Right? RAID-6 doesn't handle more than about eight disks tops well (not only will you get diminishing performance returns, your performance will decline with every new disk you add beyond a certain fairly low point), and the chances of more than two disks failing before replacing / re-balancing can occur is pretty high in such a configuration.

Comment: Weird, Dell recommends you use a RAID 50, 10, or 6 in there documentation. That being said this PS6510 is only being used as a backup target so speed is not a concern but rather redundancy balanced with capacity.

Comment: You seriously can't nest RAID levels with this thing? I see that it supports RAID 6, 10, and 50, but I don't see anything about RAID level nesting in its docs. Even a RAID 60 would be far better for this, and you'd still only lose 4 disks. Anyways, verification of such an abstraction is going to take a seriously long time, and allowing access to a portion of it before it's completed is normal.

Comment: Not as far as i know. Just RAID 50, 10, 5, 6 and 6 (accelerated) all of these RAID are then Automatically setup for you in terms of how the drives are allocated. that being said we bought this since for shear capacity we could not find anything better. Thought that does answer my question about it only giving me access to a portion of the capacity. If you throw up a answer i will mark it as correct.

Comment: I use R60 for just this kind of setup - you need to do the same, nothing else other than ZFS makes sense.

Comment: Lol sadly that is not an option on the array,  RAID 50 is the closest

Comment: *47 disk in a RAID6 and one spare drive.*  Ooof. That's horrible and *slow*. If you get a failed drive you're likely to find a few more failures before a rebuild completes. You'd get much better performance splitting that up into 4 8+2 RAID6 arrays with a few drives left over for miscellaneous uses or a bunch of 4+1 RAID5 arrays, and then using volume manager software on the client(s) if you want a single huge filesystem. If you're planning on parceling out that single huge array into multiple LUNs, you're also going to have downright *nasty* contention over all those disks.

Comment: Agreed but this device does not support this. it allow you to apply one RAID config per member of the cluster.

Comment: wow i think this unit may be FUBARed it got through verification of the RAID but somehow still only showed 26TB of usable space from 96TB RAW.... I then rebooted the member and it when it came back up it default to the other Dell Type 10 controller. when i viewed the disks on that controller it showed over half the disks as Foreign disks. i then manually added each foreign disk to the RAID and it expanded from 26TB to 53TB still about 15TB off what was the original configuration estimate of 69TB.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up fixing this by completely factory resetting the device. Then doing the initial config and letting the device sit around for around an hour before picking a RAID Configuration for the Array. As far as I can tell, the secondary controller takes a while to initialize Which somehow causes the RAID configuration to not properly be set on that controller. Hence the weird 26TB of space. Then once the array restarted it defaulted to the other controller which saw over half of the disk as foreign. You can add these disks to the array on that controller but since the other controller already has those disk marked as active it does not increase the usable capacity. Note that an older firmware (5.0.4) was on this device but it was out of warranty so I could not get the new firmware package. That being said this is all just conjecture, but at this point the Array has been humming along for over a week without issue.

TLDR: this was caused by a weird firmware bug. Either update the firmware and factory reset the device or factory reset the device, do the initial config, wait an hour, then apply the RAID config to the array.